# How to distinguish between copy/move in importData

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop

I need to get action type during drag and drop or copy/cut and paste (copy vs. move). It is a Swing application and there is implemented `TransferHandle`. I need this information at the end of the action, in `importData` method.

For drag and drop it seems to be possible test `getUserDropAction`, like this

```java
@Override
public boolean importData(final TransferSupport support) {
    if(support.isDrop() && support.getUserDropAction() == TransferHandler.MOVE) {
        // drag and drop, MOVE
    }
}
```

...but how to get this information for cut/copy and paste? Or is there a better, universal way?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can get enough tips from the Swing tutorial which contains a working example:

- [CCP in a non-Text Component (The Java™ Tutorials > Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing > Drag and Drop and Data Transfer)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/listpaste.html)

  - [ListTransferHandler.java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/dnd/ListCutPasteProject/src/dnd/ListTransferHandler.java)

---

Whether it is **drag and drop** or **copy/cut and paste** can be determined by the `TransferSupport#isDrop()` method.

```
/**
 * Perform the actual data import.
 */
public boolean importData(TransferHandler.TransferSupport info) {
    // ...
    if (info.isDrop()) { // This is a drop
        // ...
    } else { // This is a paste
        // ...
    }
```

Use the the [TransferHandler#exportDone(...)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/TransferHandler.html#exportDone-javax.swing.JComponent-java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable-int-) method's `int action` argument to determine if it is **copy and paste** or **cut and paste**.

Since the paste is executed with the `TransferHandler#importData(...)` method, override the `TransferHandler#exportDone(...)` method that is called after the paste is completed, and if the action of the argument is `TransferHandler.MOVE`, cut the transfer source data.

If the action is anything other than `TransferHandler.MOVE`, there is no need to do anything because it is a copy.

```
/** 
 * When the export is complete, remove the old list entry if the
 * action was a move.
 */
protected void exportDone(JComponent c, Transferable data, int action) {
    if (action != MOVE) {
        return;
    }
    JList list = (JList)c;
    DefaultListModel model = (DefaultListModel)list.getModel();
    int index = list.getSelectedIndex();
    model.remove(index);
}
```

Comment: Your solution works for distinguish keyboard action (cut or copy) from mouse action (move and copy). But I need something different, as I've written in subject: move vs copy. And not in the `exportDone`, but in the `importData` (due some server communication).